# How to upload files to a sharepoint list 2019 with an html and javascript form for anonymous users?

Tags: list, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a form with html and javascript to send text and dropdown data to a sharepoint list, but now I need that form to work uploading files for anonymous users, so I want to check if it is possible to create an FBA user and authenticate by default to open form link?

Answer (score 0):

Aparently uploading attachments in SharePoint to a list item is unavailable for security matters, some work arounds that i've found is with a webpart solution.

Some threads about our problem:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/pt-br/82ba2da4-086f-4cb9-a68b-2741a695fcea/anonymous-users-cannot-attach-files-to-a-list

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/pt-br/5cc0a173-16fe-45ce-88a6-ae9dfe19953b/anonymous-user-want-to-attach-items-to-sharepoint-list